# ¿Por qué no funciona script UPDATE en php sí me muestra mensaje de confirmación exitosa?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Al ejecutar el la acción del formulario, el ajax me envía los datos al php y me muestra un mensaje de confirmación exitosa, pero en realidad no se ejecuta la actualización en la BD. Cabe mencionar que los datos están siendo recibidos correctamente.

Aquí el código AJAX

```
 $('#btn_editar').click(function(){
    var datos = $('#form_editar').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "src/test.php",
        data: datos,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Aquí el código PHP

```
include "conn.php";
        $id = utf8_decode($_POST['id']);
        $nombre = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
        $apellidos = utf8_decode($_POST['last']);
        $telefono = utf8_decode($_POST['phone']);
        $correo = utf8_decode($_POST['mail']);
        $direccion = utf8_decode($_POST['address']);
        // Creamos sentencia UPDATE
        $sql = "UPDATE cat_concesionario 
                SET nombre = '".$nombre."',
                apellidos = '".$apellidos."',
                telefono = '".$telefono."',
                mail = '".$correo."',
                direccion = '".$direccion."' 
                WHERE id_conce = '".$id."'";

        $resultado = $con->query($sql);
        if($resultado){
            $res = $nombre;
        }
        else{
            $res = "Error al modificar";
        }
        echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el [manual de JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), la función `$.serialize()` toma los elementos de tu formulario y los "serializa" en una cadena del tipo `key1=valor1&key2=valor2`.

Entonces, cuando haces `var datos = $('#form_editar').serialize();` en realidad estás enviándole a `src/test.php` una cadena que debe ser algo como `id=1&name=juan&last=perez...`. Todo esto dentro de la variable `$_POST['data']`.

Entonces, en `test.php` debes tomar `$_POST['data']` y "des-serializarlo". Puede ser algo así:

```
$data = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data');
foreach (explode('&', $data) as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Y después de esto ya tienes las variables `$id`, `$name`, `$last`, etc. para empezar a construir tu sql.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta. Ya todo anda funcionando bien.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de saber si tu sentencia SQL está correcta es capturarla y ejecutarla directamente sobre MySQL, te recomiendo insertar el siguiente código antes del if() generaras un archivo .txt el cual contendra la setencia SQL con todos los valores para que primero veas si los valores son correctos y luego la puedas ejecutar en MySQL directamente y descartar errores en PHP.

```
<?php

include "conn.php";
$id = utf8_decode($_POST['id']);
$nombre = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
$apellidos = utf8_decode($_POST['last']);
$telefono = utf8_decode($_POST['phone']);
$correo = utf8_decode($_POST['mail']);
$direccion = utf8_decode($_POST['address']);
// Creamos sentencia UPDATE
$sql = "UPDATE cat_concesionario 
SET nombre = '".$nombre."',
apellidos = '".$apellidos."',
telefono = '".$telefono."',
mail = '".$correo."',
direccion = '".$direccion."' 
WHERE id_conce = '".$id."'";

//LOG
$ar=fopen("query_".date("d-m-Y", time()).".log","a") or
die("Problemas en la creacion");
fputs($ar,date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time())."- "."$sql \n");
fclose($ar);
//FIN LOG  

$resultado = $con->query($sql);
if($resultado){
$res = $nombre;
}
else{
 $res = "Error al modificar";
}
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

hay que tener más cuidado con respecto al uso de comillas. Te dejo el código aquí:

```
include "conn.php";
    $id = utf8_decode($_POST['id']);
    $nombre = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
    $apellidos = utf8_decode($_POST['last']);
    $telefono = utf8_decode($_POST['phone']);
    $correo = utf8_decode($_POST['mail']);
    $direccion = utf8_decode($_POST['address']);
    // Creamos sentencia UPDATE
    $sql = "UPDATE cat_concesionario 
            SET nombre = '$nombre',
            apellidos = '$apellidos',
            telefono = '$telefono',
            mail = '$correo',
            direccion = '$direccion' 
            WHERE id_conce = '$id'";

    $resultado = $con->query($sql);
    if($resultado){
        $res = $nombre;
    }
    else{
        $res = "Error al modificar";
    }
    echo $res;
```

Esta es la linea que modifiqué:

```
$sql = "UPDATE cat_concesionario 
            SET nombre = '".$nombre."',
            apellidos = '".$apellidos."',
            telefono = '".$telefono."',
            mail = '".$correo."',
            direccion = '".$direccion."' 
            WHERE id_conce = '".$id."'";
```